# libmodbus cross compilation for qnx6.6.0 target

Tags: modbus, qnx, momentics

I have installed qnx6.6.0 as a guest system in VMware workstation 12.
[Picture 1. qnx6.6.0 in VMware](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLPxD.png)

Qnx6.6.0 operating system does not have any self-hosting abilities. Thus I use QNX Momentics IDE to cross compile binaries.

In my project I need to link extra libraries libmodbus. I am not able to compile in proper way libmodbus (version 3.0.6). I tried to do it in two ways:

-compile libmodbus in MinGW program(./configure && make), but in the result I got libmodbus.dll.

-compile in Ubuntu OS(./configure && make). In result I got libmodbus.so.5.0.5.

Both binaries are not possible to link into qnx project in Momentics IDE. I assume that the libmodbus compilation process, which I did is not correct. What should I put in arguments to script ./configure ? Is it possible to compile this dynamic library in Windows or Ubuntu system in order to ensure linking to QNX binary?